# Trying to implement an easily-"subclassable" Array subclass

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to subclass `Array`, following the ideas and recommendations given in [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/).

One important goal of this subclass of `Array`, which here I'm calling `ArrayBase`, is that it be itself more straightforward to subclass than `Array` itself.  I'm finding that achieving this goal is surprisingly difficult.  (But it may look this way to me because I'm a JavaScript n00b!)

Below is an implementation of `ArrayBase` that is based on the ideas presented [towards the end](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/#wrappers_prototype_chain_injection) of the article cited earlier, with some enhancements of my own.  I've also included an implementation of `ArrayBase.slice`, since it illustrates one problem with the scheme<sup>1</sup>.

```
function ArrayBase () {
  var arr = Array.prototype.constructor.apply(null, arguments);
  var ctor = arr.constructor = arguments.callee;
  arr.__proto__ = ctor.prototype;
  return arr;
}

ArrayBase.prototype = new Array;
ArrayBase.prototype.slice = function () {
  var ctor = this.constructor;
  return ctor.apply(null,
                    Array.prototype.slice.apply(this, arguments));
}

var a0 = new ArrayBase(0, 1, 2, 3);
var a1 = a0.slice(2);                 // [2, 3]
console.log(a1 instanceof ArrayBase); // true
console.log(a1 instanceof Array);     // true
```

So far, so good.  The problem happens when I now try to subclass `ArrayBase`.  I find that the only way to do this requires basically replicating the entire `ArrayBase` constructor (the only difference, very slight, happens in the first line).  As inheritance goes, this is pitiful...

```
function MyArray () {
  var arr = ArrayBase.apply(this, arguments);
  var ctor = arr.constructor = arguments.callee;
  arr.__proto__ = ctor.prototype;
  return arr;
}
MyArray.prototype = new ArrayBase;

// behavior of MyArray

var a2 = new MyArray(1, 2, 3, 0);
var a3 = a2.slice(1);                 // [2, 3, 0]
console.log(a3 instanceof MyArray);   // true
console.log(a3 instanceof ArrayBase); // true
console.log(a3 instanceof Array);     // true
console.log(a3.join(':'));            // "2:3:0"
a3[5] = 1;
console.log(a3.length);               // 6
a3.length = 2;
console.log(a3.toString())            // "2,3"
```

My questions:

> How could the duplication that exists between the `ArrayBase` and `MyArray` constructors, be eliminated, while still preserving the behavior illustrated by the lines after the `// behavior of MyArr` line?  Would the scheme work also at the time of subclassing `MyArray`?

(I'm aware of the arguments against building tall towers of inheritance, but whether they are good design or not, I want them to be at least soundly implemented.)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>If inheritance from `Array` were as I think it should be, it would not be necessary to implement `ArrayBase.slice`, but unfortunately the `slice` method that `ArrayBase` inherits from `Array` does not show the elementary OOP courtesy of returning an object of the same class as that of `this`.</sub>

Comment: Just a question before: have you checked it on IE? I just wish you luck. Seriously, I wouldn't recommend to inherit from native objects, it causes a lot of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your question, some comments on the code :-)

> ```
> var arr = Array.prototype.constructor.apply(null, arguments);
> ```

Since `Array.prototype.constructor === Array`, don't duplicate this.

> ```
> var ctor = arr.constructor = …
> ```

There's no reason to create a property here. If the `constructor` property is needed for anything, it should be inherited from that constructor's `.prototype` object.

> ```
> arguments.callee;
> ```

Don't use deprecated `arguments.callee`! You know that it points to `ArrayBase`.

> ```
> arr.__proto__ = ctor.prototype;
> ```

You probably know that `__proto__` is nonstandard (and does especially not work in IE), but we need it here for the prototype injection technique. Still, don't forget this fact!

> ```
> ArrayBase.prototype = new Array;
> ```

Do [not use `new` for setting up inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572)! You don't want to invoke an initialiser (i.e. "constructor") here. Use `Object.create` instead.

Now, back to your question:

> How can the duplication that exists between my `ArrayBase` and `MyArray` constructors be eliminated?

Actually you have used that concept already. Your `ArrayBase.prototype.slice` implementation works with every subclass - constructing instances of `this.constructor` again. You can use the same method for the `ArrayBase` constructor:

```
function ArrayBase() {
  var arr = Array.apply(null, arguments);
  var ctor = this.constructor;
  arr.__proto__ = ctor.prototype;
  return arr;
}
/* irrelevant for the answer, but helpful:
ArrayBase.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype, {
  constructor: {value: ArrayBase}
});
Object.keys(Array.prototype).forEach(function(k) {
  if (typeof Array.prototype[k] != "function") return;
  ArrayBase.prototype[k] = function() {
    var arr = Array.prototype[k].apply(this, arguments);
    if (Array.isArray(arr))
      arr.__proto__ = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    return arr;
  };
});
*/
function MyArray() {
  return ArrayBase.apply(this, arguments);
}
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(ArrayBase.prototype, {
  constructor: {value: MyArray}
});
```